# How can I handle 'ImageNotFoundException' consistently across different computers when using 'pyautogui.locateOnScreen'?

Tags: python, exception, pyautogui

I have a script that searches for images on the screen using `pyautogui.locateOnScreen`. On my personal computer, if it doesn't find the image, it goes to the `elif` branch (which is perfect). However, on my work computer, if it doesn't find the image, it raises an exception `ImageNotFoundException` and halts the execution.

```
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img/run.png', grayscale=False, confidence=0.6) is not None:
        locationrun1 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('img/run.png', grayscale=False, confidence=0.8)
        pyautogui.moveTo(locationrun1)
        pyautogui.click()
        print("Run away")

elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img/run2.png', grayscale=False, confidence=0.6) is not None:
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1.8, 2.1))
        keyboard.press("w")
        locationrun2 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('img/run2.png', grayscale=False, confidence=0.8)
        pyautogui.moveTo(locationrun2)
        pyautogui.click()
```

How can I troubleshoot this issue and ensure consistent behavior across different computers? I want the flow to go through the 'elif' statement if it doesn't find the 'run.png' photo to check the 'run2.png', instead of raising the exception (as it does on one of my computers, but not on the other). Why?

Comment: I believe pyautogui recently changed how that function works.  In older versions it would return None, but in newer versions it throws an exception.  The solution is to install the same version on both computers.

Comment: I have same versions on both

pyautogui==0.9.54

Comment: How did you find the exact version on both computers?  Please show us the exact output.

Comment: AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 174, in wrapper
    raise ImageNotFoundException  # Raise PyAutoGUI's ImageNotFoundException.

Comment: I don't see the pyautogui version number in that output.  How is that output related to the pyautogui version number?

Comment: Ah? to see the version of pyautogui, I did 
'pip list' on the working computer, looked at the versions of all the libraries, and installed them on the second one.

Comment: If you use `pip install` but you do not also say `--upgrade`, it will potentially install an older version.  That is why I wanted to see the specific versions on both computers.

Comment: Run this code on both computers: `import pyautogui; print(pyautogui.__version__)`

Comment: yes, i got the same on both
>>> import pyautogui; print(pyautogui.__version__)
0.9.54
>>>

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe that isn't the reason then?  I thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test this is using unit tests with different images that represent different configurations (i.e. your work computer and your home computer). You can achieve this using `pytest` easily by doing something like:

```
import pytest
from PIL import Image

def test_clicks_images(monkeypatch):
    def fake_screenshot(*args, **kwargs):
        # Fake the pyscreeze screenshot function so it returns the previously saved image
        # instead of taking a screenshot
        im = Image.open(f"path/to/previously/saved/screenshot.png")
        im.load()
        return im

    monkeypatch.setattr("pyscreeze.screenshot", fake_screenshot)

   #ensure that img/run2.png is found in screenshot.png thus ensuring that it will find it in the computer producing that screenshot
   assert len(pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img/run2.png', grayscale=False, confidence=0.6)) != 0
```

It is very important to ensure that the screenshots you use for testing replicate as close as possible the environment (no rescaling or anything)